# How to impelement post-proccesing for yolo v3 or v4 onnx models in ML.Net

Tags: yolo, ml.net, onnx, post-processing

I followed [this microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/object-detection-onnx) and there was no problem. but i wanted to change model to yolo v3 or v4. I get the YOLOv4 onnx model from [onnx/models](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/object_detection_segmentation/yolov4) and was able to get all three array of float outputs of yolov4 onnx model but the problem is with post-processing and i can't get proper boundinboxes from these outputs.

I changed all things like anchors, strides, output grid sizes, some functios and... in microsoft tutorial src code to be compatible with yolov4.  but I cant get proper results.
I checked all my code with [python implementation](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/object_detection_segmentation/yolov4) but i don't know where is the problem.
Does anyone have a link or knows how to implement yolo v3 or v4 onnx models in c# with ML.Net

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is not possible to directly port microsoft's tutorial from YOLO v2 to v3 as it relies on the inputs and outputs of each model.

As a side note, I did a port of another YOLO v3 model to ML.Net in [this GitHub repo: 'YOLOv3MLNet'](https://github.com/BobLd/YOLOv3MLNet). It contains a fully functionning ML.Net pipeline.

**I've also made the code of this answer available here:**

- **[YOLO v3 with ML.Net](https://github.com/BobLd/YOLOv3MLNet/tree/master/YOLOV3MLNetSO)**
- **[YOLO v4 with ML.Net](https://github.com/BobLd/YOLOv4MLNet)**

To go back to your models, I'll take the YOLO v3 (available in the onnx/models repo) as an example. A good explaination of the model can be found [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/yolo-v3-theory-explained-33100f6d193).

First advice would be to look at the model using [Netron](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/netron). Doing so, you will see the input and output layers. They also describe these layers in the onnx/models documentation.

[Netron's yolov3-10 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKR0y.png)

(I see in Netron that this particular YOLO v3 model also does some post-processing by doing the Non-maximum supression step.)

- Input layers names: `input_1`, `image_shape`
- Ouput layers names: `yolonms_layer_1/ExpandDims_1:0`, `yolonms_layer_1/ExpandDims_3:0`, `yolonms_layer_1/concat_2:0`

As per the model documentation, the input shapes are:

> Resized image (1x3x416x416) Original image size (1x2) which is [image.size['1], image.size[0]]

We first need to define the ML.Net input and output classes as follow:

```cs
public class YoloV3BitmapData
{
    [ColumnName("bitmap")]
    [ImageType(416, 416)]
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

    [ColumnName("width")]
    public float ImageWidth => Image.Width;

    [ColumnName("height")]
    public float ImageHeight => Image.Height;
}

public class YoloV3Prediction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ((52 x 52) + (26 x 26) + 13 x 13)) x 3 = 10,647.
    /// </summary>
    public const int YoloV3BboxPredictionCount = 10_647;

    /// <summary>
    /// Boxes
    /// </summary>
    [ColumnName("yolonms_layer_1/ExpandDims_1:0")]
    public float[] Boxes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scores
    /// </summary>
    [ColumnName("yolonms_layer_1/ExpandDims_3:0")]
    public float[] Scores { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Concat
    /// </summary>
    [ColumnName("yolonms_layer_1/concat_2:0")]
    public int[] Concat { get; set; }
}
```

We then create the ML.Net pipeline and load the prediction engine:

```cs
// Define scoring pipeline
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(inputColumnName: "bitmap", outputColumnName: "input_1", imageWidth: 416, imageHeight: 416, resizing: ResizingKind.IsoPad)
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "input_1", outputAsFloatArray: true, scaleImage: 1f / 255f))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("image_shape", "height", "width"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(shapeDictionary: new Dictionary<string, int[]>() { { "input_1", new[] { 1, 3, 416, 416 } } },
                    inputColumnNames: new[]
                    {
                        "input_1",
                        "image_shape"
                    },
                    outputColumnNames: new[]
                    {
                        "yolonms_layer_1/ExpandDims_1:0",
                        "yolonms_layer_1/ExpandDims_3:0",
                        "yolonms_layer_1/concat_2:0"
                    },
                    modelFile: @"D:\yolov3-10.onnx"));

// Fit on empty list to obtain input data schema
var model = pipeline.Fit(mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new List<YoloV3BitmapData>()));

// Create prediction engine
var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<YoloV3BitmapData, YoloV3Prediction>(model);
```

**NB**: We need to define the `shapeDictionary` parameter because they are not completly defined in the model.

As per the model documentation, the output shapes are:

> The model has 3 outputs. boxes: (1x'n_candidates'x4), the coordinates of all anchor boxes, scores: (1x80x'n_candidates'), the scores of all anchor boxes per class, indices: ('nbox'x3), selected indices from the boxes tensor. The selected index format is (batch_index, class_index, box_index).

The function below will help you process the results, I leave it to you fine-tune it.

```cs
public IReadOnlyList<YoloV3Result> GetResults(YoloV3Prediction prediction, string[] categories)
{
    if (prediction.Concat == null || prediction.Concat.Length == 0)
    {
        return new List<YoloV3Result>();
    }

    if (prediction.Boxes.Length != YoloV3Prediction.YoloV3BboxPredictionCount * 4)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    if (prediction.Scores.Length != YoloV3Prediction.YoloV3BboxPredictionCount * categories.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    List<YoloV3Result> results = new List<YoloV3Result>();

    // Concat size is 'nbox'x3 (batch_index, class_index, box_index)
    int resulstCount = prediction.Concat.Length / 3;
    for (int c = 0; c < resulstCount; c++)
    {
        var res = prediction.Concat.Skip(c * 3).Take(3).ToArray();

        var batch_index = res[0];
        var class_index = res[1];
        var box_index = res[2];

        var label = categories[class_index];
        var bbox = new float[]
        {
            prediction.Boxes[box_index * 4],
            prediction.Boxes[box_index * 4 + 1],
            prediction.Boxes[box_index * 4 + 2],
            prediction.Boxes[box_index * 4 + 3],
        };
        var score = prediction.Scores[box_index + class_index * YoloV3Prediction.YoloV3BboxPredictionCount];

        results.Add(new YoloV3Result(bbox, label, score));
    }

    return results;
}
```

In this version of the model, they are 80 classes (see the model's GitHub documentation for the link).

You can use the above like this:

```cs
// load image
string imageName = "dog_cat.jpg";
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(imageFolder, imageName))))
{
    // predict
    var predict = predictionEngine.Predict(new YoloV3BitmapData() { Image = bitmap });

    var results = GetResults(predict, classesNames);

    // draw predictions
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var y1 = result.BBox[0];
            var x1 = result.BBox[1];
            var y2 = result.BBox[2];
            var x2 = result.BBox[3];

            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);
            using (var brushes = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red)))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(brushes, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
            }

            g.DrawString(result.Label + " " + result.Confidence.ToString("0.00"),
                         new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Blue, new PointF(x1, y1));
        }

        bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(imageOutputFolder, Path.ChangeExtension(imageName, "_processed" + Path.GetExtension(imageName))));
    }
}
```

You can find a [result example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5pbH.jpg).

Comment: The greatest answer I've seen in stackoverflow Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi bld. I have tried to follow the YoloV5 solution you made. The yolo5_incl branch but there is an error in the code. And also, using your input data(mode etc) it still does not compile. But once modifying the ApplyOnnxModel and also add recursionLimit it works. But the results are just an image full of boxes. I can see the image for all the labels and boxes drawn. Any ideas to proceed? I would very much appriciate you support.